# Does HIVE accept CTRL character?

Tags: hive, newline, hiveql, ddl

Does Hive accept <kbd>CTRL</kbd> lines terminated by `'\r\n'`? I have to generate a text file to  Windows and wish to use CRLF for line termination. If so, can you let me know whether I gave the correct one or not?

LINES TERMINATED BY `'\r\n'`

Comment: AFAIK, the Hive SerDe used for text files matches *any* usual line terminator i.e. `\n` (Linux etc.) or `\r\n` (Windows) or `\r` (older Macs). Just upload a Windows file to HDFS and make the test.

Answer (score 0):

In the hive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries), line separator is a `char`, hence it should not accept two characters !

> ```
> row_format   : DELIMITED 
>     [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]]
>     [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char]
>     [MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY char] [LINES TERMINATED BY char]
>     [NULL DEFINED AS char] (Note: Only available starting with Hive 0.13)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Currently only `\n` is supported.
Check out this JIRA tickets.

- [Allow other characters for LINES TERMINATED BY](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5999)
- [Row Delimiter other than '\n' throws error in Hive.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11996)

Demo

```
hive> create table t (i int) row format delimited lines terminated by '\r\n' location '/tmp';
FAILED: SemanticException 1:64 LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now. Error encountered near token ''\r\n''
hive>
```